# awk + Print lines before and after match

Tags: bash, awk

I know this is a repetitive discussion for most query raised by many person, but I didn't get any apt solution specifically and looking only to awk command utiltiy.

I'm try to filter the MAC and IP address from the ifconfig output.

```
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
      inet addr:192.xx.xx.xx  Bcast:192.xx.xx.xx  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Currently I'm trying to print by matching HWADDR then checking second line, followed by next line.

```
awk '/HWaddr/{printf $NF;printf " ";getline;print $2;}' <filename> | cut -c1-18,24-
```

xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 192.168.xx.xx

my question how to search to previous line. for eg:- If I match IP address for second line , then how to reverse search for the first line , something like

```
 awk '/192/{printf $2;printf " ";<unknown>;}' <filename>
```

Here I'm matching for IP starts from 192, based on that checking the previous line. May I know what is the reverse search for getline, I meant what's the directive for reverse search

looking only with awk utility

Comment: please try to select any of the answer as correct answer(out of all answers) to close the thread fully. I see you never do it.

Comment: Check the manual page for `grep` on your system. Some implementations have an option to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is simply to store the previous line in a variable, and then reference that when you need it.  For example, with the following `awk` script:

```
/192/ {print lastline}
{ lastline=$0 }
```

If I give it the following put:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:00:6a:7d:06:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.24/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 67513sec preferred_lft 67513sec
    inet6 fe80::5da1:2401:a725:d2e0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I get as output:

```
link/ether 64:00:6a:7d:06:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Of course, interfaces can have multiple addresses, and this would fail
if your interface look like, for example:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:00:6a:7d:06:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.32.1/24 brd 172.16.32.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 67513sec preferred_lft 67513sec
    inet 192.168.1.24/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 67513sec preferred_lft 67513sec
    inet6 fe80::5da1:2401:a725:d2e0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Rather than looking at "the previous line", it's better to explicitly
record the MAC address:

```
/192/ {print hwaddr}
/link\/ether/ {hwaddr=$0}
```

This will always print out the value of the previous `link/ether` line.

Comment: BINGO, It looks very near to my solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{print $2 OFS prev} {prev=$0}' Input_file
```